# Implement Vim-like imap mapping in sublime-text 3

Tags: vim, mapping, sublimetext3

I would like to have `;` inserted at the end of line, when I press `;;` while in insert mode. What would be mapping for that in `sublime-text 3`?

Somtehing like:

```
inoremap ;; <C-o>A;
```

in `VIM`.

So far, I managed to get to `EOL` I am currently on, but have no idea on how to chain other command to insert `;`. I was not able to find anything in documentation on running multiple commands in sequence.

```
{
    "keys": [";", ";"],
    "command": "move_to", "args": { "to": "eol" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wasn't able to find any native-to-editor solution to this,
luckily there is a plugin called `Chain of Command`

```
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Chain%20of%20Command
```

Then you can put this into user keymap settings file:

```
{
    "keys": [";", ";"],
    "command": "chain",
    "args": {
    "commands": [
        [ "move_to", { "to": "eol" }],
        [ "insert", { "characters": ";" } ]
    ]
    },
    // with a help of this line, command won't get executed
    // if in command_mode (vintage mode enabled), so it applies to insert mode
    // only.
    "context": [ { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false } ]
}
```